# How to implement a toolbar as a header of UICollectionView

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

What I want to do is a toolbar that works just like Apple's Podcasts app:

[image: Apple's podcast app screenshot]

I tried using a custom UICollectionReusableView and using it as a Supplementary View but I keep finding new bugs and it got me wondering if this is the correct approach.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader is the correct way to implement header of UICollectionView. There is a bug in UICollectionView which may crash the app when a section with non-nil supplementary view is reloaded. It is hard to tell if it is the problem unless you provide more information.

If it is, a workaround is to put the toolbar into a UICollectionViewCell instead of UICollectionReusableView.

Comment: I've had many bugs, specially regarding including the UISearchBar in the UIToolbar (I ended up adding the UISearchBar on top of the toolbar, following some suggestions I found here at SO).

But one that I haven't been able to fix is that, whenever I delete the first cell in the collection (using the deleteItemsAtIndexPaths method), the header "flashes": it fades out and then fades back in. Any idea what may be causing this?

Comment: I got the same issue. Use "reloadData" if you don't want animations.

Comment: I actually want the animations, I just didn't want the toolbar to "flash" like this, since it does not "flash" when I delete other elements.

Comment: In this case, overwrite the toolbar's "setAlpha:". Make it simply returns without changing the toolbar's alpha transparency.